# The Number of Short Vectors in a Lattice

Tags: lattices, algorithms, nt.number-theory

Given a lattice $L = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m} \mathbb{Z}v_i$ (the $v_i$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and a number $c > 0$, can one quickly compute or find a good estimate on the number of lattice vectors $v$ with $|v| \leq c$ without actually enumerating these vectors?  The basis $v_1,\ldots, v_m$ of the lattice can be assumed to be LLL reduced.

Also asked at: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/the-number-of-short-vectors-in-a-lattice

Comment: Of course, for large $c$ this approximates the volume of a ball of radius $c$, divided by the covolume of the lattice, and error estimates are an important part of number theory about which I know almost nothing (Gauss circle problem, etc.)  On the other hand, if you want to know how many vectors have a particular length (for example, the shortest length) there are so-called mass formulae dealing with such problems, due to Siegel, Minkowski, and others, although there are subtleties if the lattice in question is not alone in its genus.

Comment: For a range of relatively small values of $c$ and $m$ the sphere decoding algorithm could probably be tweaked to produce an answer, but it would also enumerate them, so you want something faster. But in that low range of $c$ IIRC the question of whether the number of short vectors is positive belongs to some discouraging complexity class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this problem one typically employs the so-called Gaussian heuristic:

> if $K$ is a measurable subset of the
>   span of the $n$-dimensional lattice
>   $L$, then $| K \cap L | \approx
> > \mbox{vol}(K)/\det(L)$.

In particular, the case for $K$ a ball is used in some (enumerative) SVP/CVP solvers. See $\S 5$ of
["Algorithms for the shortest and closest lattice vector problems"](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3AAhvHFVKJM6gJ%3Aperso.ens-lyon.fr/guillaume.hanrot/Papers/iwcc.pdf+%2522Algorithms+for+the+Shortest+and+Closest+Lattice%2522&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgobFF10e7VdXrwpPBbjVxoAKFKPeLIKDgr_t23PLdWk0RYK1NTG2L_0jkyYMoCIGfwombzc8QWsOc77syabUW4z41kyggPGw7Ku9g1bw_OviJHeDpoiw03Szwp0CIWm0VU_ass&sig=AHIEtbQS1o9KO1WzlxdFen5jkXJ4Ff8UAA&pli=1)
by Hanrot, Pujol and Stehlé.