# Upper bound on the number of shortest vectors in a lattice

Tags: lattices

Given a Lattice $L$ (e.g. by its Gram-Matrix or via a basis) I would like to know whether there is an upper bound on the number of shortest vectors in $L$. Available information on $L$ includes dimension, rank as well as an upper and a lower bound on the minimum of $L$.

The question arises in the following context: The group of automorphisms of $L$ ($Aut(L)$) acts on the set of shortest vectors of $L$ and an upper bound on the cardinality of this set would yield some information on which stabilizers are to be expected.

Comment: See this earlier MO question: "Estimating the number of short vectors in a lattice": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71052/

Comment: Also see SPLAG (= *Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups* by Conway and Sloane) about "kissing numbers".   [The acronym "SPLAG", though risible, is not disrespectful since the authors use it themselves.]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I somehow missed the quite obvious connection between my question and the kissing number.

Sadly there does not seem to be a naive upper bound and the number of results in dimension 248 is rather limited.